# Catering for android Google Play Services on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-notifications

I have made an android app and I am trying to work on its backwards compatability to Android Jelly Bean.  The only limitation I have right now is Firebase Notifications and Google Play Services because I am targeting a low income market who likely won't have money to update their Google Play Services to the latest.  What versions of them should I realistically target to reduce the chance that the user has to download a new Google Play Services?

Additionally I can't get version numbers for firebase from before 2015.  I do see that Firebase and Google Play support a minimum Android API of 14 which is before my target market but although the latest versions of both will work on API 14, I cannot expect my user base to download 42mb of Google Play Services over mobile data just to use my app.

Comment: IMO, if a user couldn't afford to update their Play Services, I'm pretty sure they wouldn't even consider on trying any other app other than what they already have installed.

Comment: Well the play services on 5.1 is 30mb on device.  The Play services on 7 is 200mb on device.  Thats quite big download.

Comment: It is. What I'm trying to say is, old Play Services may contain some old bugs that is fixed by updating it and if you choose to try and cater to the older versions (it's cool, best practice is to support as much devices as possible) versions, it might produce some *weird* behaviors.